# Array pointers and functions

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I have to write a C program to do the following:

- Write a function that takes three arguments: a pointer to the first
  element of a range in an array, a pointer to the element following
  the end of a range in an array, and an int value. Have the function
  set each element of the array to the int value.

My code is not working.  Here is what I have so far.  Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int listNumbers[3]{ 1,2,3 };
void Sorter(int *first, int * last, int *value);
int * first = &listNumbers[0];
int * last = &listNumbers[2];
int value;

int main() {

    printf("your list numbers are:\n");
    int i;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        printf("%d", listNumbers[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("enter an integer:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &value);

    Sorter( first, last, &value);

    printf("your new list numbers are:\n");
    int j;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        printf("%d", listNumbers[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
void Sorter(int *first, int * last, int *value) {

    int i=0;
    printf("value = %d\n", &value);
    *first = value;

    while (i <= *last) {
        *(first + i) = value;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the task supposed to be to set each element of the *range* designated by the two pointers?  That seems to fit better than what you've actually written, to set each element in the (whole) array.

Comment: Note that the global array is invalidly initialized in C — I reserve judgement on whether it is valid in C++ (it might be in modern enough C++).  The other three global variables are unnecessary.  You should avoid global variables as much as possible.  Sometimes they're necessary; here, they are not.  Even the array could/should be defined and initialized inside `main()`.  Also, the name `Sorter` is a malapropism for `Setter` or thereabouts; you're not sorting the array but setting its elements to a single value.  (I suppose that if you set the whole array, it is thereafter sorted, but …)

Answer (score 1):

First, work out the different between the 2 pointers.

```
int count = last - first + 1;
```

The compiler will automatically divide by the size of an integer. We add `1` to make the range inclusive. Now just iterate through each element:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    first[i] = value;
}
```

Also, why are you passing the value as a pointer? This should just be a value.

```
void Sorter(int *first, int *last, int value) {
```

And when you call it...

```
Sorter(first, last, value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Sorter` function does not satisfy the problem criteria.  The parameters are supposed to be two pointers into an array, and an **`int`**.  Your function instead accepts three pointers.

You could nevertheless have made it implement at least the apparent spirit of the exercise, by using the value to which the third argument points as the fill value, but you don't do that.  Instead you assign the pointer itself to each array element.  *That* ought to at least elicit a warning from your compiler, and you ought not to be ignoring its warnings, especially when your code it not doing what you think it should.

Furthermore, the `last` pointer is expected to point to just past the last element to set, but you use it as if it points to an integer offset from the start pointer.  This is almost the opposite of the previous problem: here, you need to use the pointer value itself, not the `int` to which it points.